# Is using LocalBroadcastManager the most appropriate way to send app-wide events?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm wondering if `LocalBroadcastManager` is better than method calls to `Objects` that are subscribed to the event publisher, and if the overhead (if any) is worth it.

I'm working on a Chat app, and a sample process includes passing a newly-received raw message to an `SQLite` database archive, then alerting an `Activity` that the database has been updated so it can get a new collection of messages. Right now, what happens is once a `MessageReceiver` gets a new message, it has a `DatabaseInterface` add that message to the database, then alerts an `Activity` via a method call. As far as I know, this couples the `MessageReceiver` and the `Activity`, and, if I recall correctly, that's bad. I liked the idea of using [Guava EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained), but currently, the most recent Android API 8-compatible release (11.2) only has the beta version. I thought of implementing my own using `Handlers`, but remembered the `BroadcastReceiver` and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this is a good use case for `LocalBroadcastManager` and what I would use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Out of curiosity though, what would **NOT** constitute a good use-case?

Comment: This answer is a little bit short. Could you maybe list some of the alternatives that are available for this kind of behaviour and which is most appropriate in which situation.